# LaTeX: Background image for one page only with no hoffset

Tags: margins, backgrounds, eso-pic

I am using `\documentclass{article}`, how would I create one page with backround image without margins, so the background image would span the whole page?

I am using this:

```
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\newcommand\BackgroundPic{%
\put(0,0){%
\parbox[b][\paperheight]{\paperwidth}{%
\vfill
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight,%
keepaspectratio]{img0016.png}%
\vfill
}}}
```

Then for the page this:

```
\newpage
%\newgeometry{left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2cm}
\AddToShipoutPicture*{\BackgroundPic}
\section*{Something, some text}
%\restoregeometry
```

The result is this:

[image]

Top and bottom margins are 0, so it is OK, how can I get rid of the white lines just for this one page?

Thank you very much

Comment: You need to change the geometry if you want to keep `keepaspectratio`. If you drop that key, the picture will fill the full page but get "deformed". That is to say, either the paper geometry accidentally fits the dimensions of that graphics or you need to make some compromise.

Comment: @Schrödinger's cat , yes I already tried that, the picture unfortunately gets deformed, I was thinking if its possible to basically zoom in (i would sacrifice part of the image - top and bot, to keep the aspect ratio), do you know if this is possible? I mean is it possible in LaTeX? In case it is not possible I could just do some adjustments in Gimp and call it a day, but I do not think that is the best solution. Thank you very much

Comment: `\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,keepaspectratio,clip]{img0016.png}` This seems to kind of zoom in without distortion.

Comment: Yes, that's another possibility, As the key `clip` indicates, it clips, i.e. truncates, the graphics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,keepaspectratio,clip]{img0016.png}`
Solved my problem.